# Commons Logging bundle in OSGi runtime

Tags: osgi, slf4j, equinox, apache-commons-logging

I am currently trying to get a bundled started in Equinox.

This bundle requires commons-logging.

I tried including the latest commons-logging jar from Maven Central. No luck.

I then moved to slf4j. This is my current status from the OSGi console:

```
11      ACTIVE      jcl.over.slf4j_1.6.6
12      ACTIVE      slf4j.api_1.6.6
                    Fragments=14
14      RESOLVED    slf4j.simple_1.6.6
                    Master=12
```

In the logs I see the following exception:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-07-09 11:36:56.157
!MESSAGE Error starting bundle: initial@file:/C:/test/slf4j-simple-1.6.6.jar
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: A fragment bundle cannot be started: slf4j.simple_1.6.6 [14]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleFragment.startWorker(BundleFragment.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startBundle(EclipseStarter.java:1119)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startBundles(EclipseStarter.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.loadBasicBundles(EclipseStarter.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:151)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-07-09 11:36:56.205
!MESSAGE Bundle slf4j.simple_1.6.6 [14] is not active.
```

What is the best way to get a commons-logging compatible bundle up and running in Equinox 3.8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`slf4j-simple` is a fragment and fragments cannot be started.

Did you list it in your config.ini with `@start` at the end? Just remove that.

Answer (score 1):

From OSGi Service Platform Core Specification

```
A Fragment bundle must enter the resolved state only if it has been successfully
attached to its host bundle.

All class or resource loading of a fragment is handled through the host’s
class loader, a fragment must never have its own class loader. Fragment bundles
are treated as if they are an intrinsic part of their host.
```

Many times we start the fragment bundle which then results  into the `org.osgi.framework.BundleException: A fragment bundle cannot be started Exception.`

As per the specification there is no need to start the fragment bundle. Its not a problem of your code.